# How to set text's colour based on a class/words in the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm continuing on making a Loot Bot simulator and I've nearly finished the Item Log! The button works and lists the items collected. Now I want it to colour the text based on whether it was Normal, Rare, Epic or Legendary. It says what type of rarity it is at the start of it. Any easy ways?

Also I want it to show the amount of Legendaries, Epics, Rares and Normals they have. It should be in the image below as well.

The blue bit circled is what I want changing:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/vrDNo]

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home |OWLBS</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type=text/css>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chance.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/spec-loot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/engine.js"></script>
<body>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid__item large--one-third logo">
          <h1>
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"><span class="loot">OW</span><span class="junkie">LBS</span></a>
            <span class="version">This is not made by me, I edited another file!</span>
          </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="grid__item large--two-thirds medium-down--hide nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid__item item-section">
        <img id="box" src="images/loot-box.png" alt="Loot Box">
        <ul id="crate"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="small-wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid__item center">
        <a class="btn yellow" onclick="openBox()" onmouseover="shakeBox()">OPEN LOOT BOX</a>
        <a class="btn blue btn-toggle" onclick="itemLog(this)" id="plus" href="#">Item Log <i id="bt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <div class="grid__item center">
        <ul id="itemlog" style="display: none;" class="in-use"></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="grid__item center stats">
      <div class="grid center">

          <div class="grid__item one-quarter small--one-whole">
            <p>Normal:  <span id="white-stat">0</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="grid__item one-quarter small--one-whole">
            <p>Rare:  <span id="blue-stat">0</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="grid__item one-quarter small--one-whole">
            <p>Epic:  <span id="purple-stat">0</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="grid__item one-quarter small--one-whole">
            <p>Legendary:  <span id="orange-stat">0</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid__item center">
        <div class="note"> Only for overwatch fans!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS(engine):

```
var crate
var openSound = new Audio('open-box.ogg');
var results = [];
var isRunning = false;

$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});

function itemLog(btn) {
  var hide = document.getElementById("itemlog")
  if (btn.id.match("plus")) {
      btn.id = "minus";
      hide.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    btn.id = "plus";
    hide.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function openBox(){

  if(isRunning == false){
    //Reset Crate
    results = [];
    setTimeout(delay,1750);
    setTimeout(hideBox,750);
    setTimeout(deleteCards,1050);
    openSound.play();
    $('#box').animateCss('bounceOutUp');
    $('#item0').animateCss('bounceOutUp');
    $('#item1').animateCss('bounceOutUp');
    $('#item2').animateCss('bounceOutUp');
    $('#item3').animateCss('bounceOutUp');

    isRunning = true;
  }
}

function deleteCards(){
  $( "#item0" ).remove();
  $( "#item1" ).remove();
  $( "#item2" ).remove();
  $( "#item3" ).remove();
}

function hideBox(){
  $( "#box" ).remove();
}

function delay(){
  setTimeout(setBox,250);

}

function setBox(){


  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    //Randomize Loot
    crate = chance.weighted(loot, weights);
    results.push(crate);
    console.log(crate);
  }

  cratespec = chance.weighted(specloot, specweights);
  results.push(cratespec);

  endresults = chance.shuffle(results);
  displayBox();

}

function displayBox(){
  //Add to list
  for(i = 0; i < endresults.length; i++){
    var ul = document.getElementById("crate");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var node = document.createElement("LI");    
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(endresults[i]));
    li.setAttribute("id", "item" + i);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(span);

    //Check Quality and Strip
    var str = $("#item" + i).text();
    console.log(str);
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(str);  
    node.appendChild(textnode)
    document.getElementById("itemlog").appendChild(node);  
     if(endresults[i].indexOf("Normal") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("normal animated bounceInDown");
      $("#item" + i ).find('span').text(str.substring(7));
    }
    if (endresults[i].indexOf("Rare") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("rare animated bounceInDown");
      $("#item" + i).find('span').text(str.substring(5));
    }
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Epic") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("epic animated bounceInDown");
      $("#item" + i).find('span').text(str.substring(5));
    }
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Lgnd") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("legendary animated bounceInDown");
      $("#item" + i).find('span').text(str.substring(5));
    }

    //Check Hero
    //Generic
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Spray") || endresults[i].indexOf("Coins") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("generic");
    }
    //orisa
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Orisa") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("orisa");
    }

    //sombra
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Sombra") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("sombra");
    }
    //ana
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Ana") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("ana");
    }
    //bastion
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Bastion") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("bastion");
    }
    //dva
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("D.Va") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("dva");
    }
    //genji
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Genji") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("genji");
    }
    //hanzo
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Hanzo") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("hanzo");
    }
    //junkrat
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Junkrat") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("junkrat");
    }
    //lucio
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Lucio") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("lucio");
    }
    //McCree
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("McCree") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("mccree");
    }
    //Reaper
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Reaper") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("reaper");
    }
    //Mei
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Mei") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("mei");
    }
    //Mercy
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Mercy") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("mercy");
    }
    //Pharah
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Pharah") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("pharah");
    }
    //Reinhardt
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Reinhardt") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("reinhardt");
    }
    //Roadhog
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Roadhog") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("roadhog");
    }
    //Solider76
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Soldier: 76") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("soldier");
    }
    //Symmetra
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Symmetra") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("symmetra");
    }
    //Torbjorn
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Torbjorn") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("torbjorn");
    }
    //Tracer
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Tracer") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("tracer");
    }
    //Widowmaker
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Widowmaker") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("widowmaker");
    }
    //Winston
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Winston") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("winston");
    }
    //Zarya
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Zarya") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("zarya");
    }
    //Zenyatta
    if(endresults[i].indexOf("Zenyatta") !=-1){
      $("#item" + i).addClass("zenyatta");
    }

  }
  isRunning = false;
}

function shakeBox(){
  $("#box").addClass("shakebox");
  setTimeout(removeShake,820);
}

function removeShake(){
  $("#box").removeClass("shakebox");
  setTimeout(shakeBox,1820);
}
```

[CSS](https://pastebin.com/ut8zJ7HX)

***If you need any more files just ask! I haven't shown animate.css, chance.js, loot.js or spec-loot.js***

Comment: Where's the code that populates that textbox?

Comment: @SpyderScript For the item log: <div class="grid__item center">
        <ul id="itemlog" style="display: none;" class="in-use"></ul>
      </div>

Comment: @SpyderScript For the Normal, Legendary, Rare and Epic counter: https://pastebin.com/LxchM1Fd

Comment: var textnode = document.createTextNode(str);  
    node.appendChild(textnode)
    document.getElementById("itemlog").appendChild(node);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're already adding some classes to your list items, mainly `normal`, `rare`, `epic`, and `legendary`. Why not add some corresponding CSS rules? For example:

```
.normal {
  color: gray;
}
.rare {
  color: green;
}
.epic {
  color: purple;
}
.legendary {
  color: gold;
}
```

**EDIT**
You should try to add the same classes to your `textnodes` as you are to your cards, then use those classes for the appropriate CSS. For example:

```
//Check Quality and Strip
var str = $("#item" + i).text();
console.log(str);
var textnode = document.createTextNode(str);  

document.getElementById("itemlog").appendChild(node);  

if(endresults[i].indexOf("Normal") !=-1){
  $("#item" + i).addClass("normal animated bounceInDown");
  $("#item" + i ).find('span').text(str.substring(7));
  // Add 'normal' class to textnode
  textnode.className = 'normal';
}
if (endresults[i].indexOf("Rare") !=-1){
  $("#item" + i).addClass("rare animated bounceInDown");
  $("#item" + i).find('span').text(str.substring(5));
  // etc.
  textnode.className = 'rare';
}
if(endresults[i].indexOf("Epic") !=-1){
  $("#item" + i).addClass("epic animated bounceInDown");
  $("#item" + i).find('span').text(str.substring(5));
  textnode.className = 'epic';
}
if(endresults[i].indexOf("Lgnd") !=-1){
  $("#item" + i).addClass("legendary animated bounceInDown");
  $("#item" + i).find('span').text(str.substring(5));
  textnode.className = 'legendary';
}

node.appendChild(textnode);
```

Comment: They already have colors and that is for the card ones. Could I make a sensor so if it has the word Normal in it goes grey? etc.

Comment: ? Are you going to reply?

Comment: @SyderScript Why doesn't this work? https://pastebin.com/vXAAWtV5 & https://pastebin.com/4mrJBRUa